# вызов итератора в методе @Produces приводит к рекурсивному вызову этого метода-poducer`а

Tags: java, java-ee, websphere

доброе время суток. подскажите где я ошибся. не получается реализовать метод-producer для иньекции. при попытке получить итератор из Instace вызывается новый экземпляр класса с методом-producer-ом, что приводит к рекрсивному вызову метода-produсer-а
вот тут 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992641/java-cdi-dynamically-selecting-an-implementation-based-on-qualifier
есть похожая проблема, но вроде бы у меня не может получиться так, что в instance попадал бы класс-producer, да и вызов нового экземпляра осуществляется на этапе вызова итератора 
Iterator it = instance.iterator();
а не на этапе перебора 
целевой класс HttpAmClientTransportBean.class
в свою очередь является наследником абстрактного Generic`а 
BaseAmClientTransport

Класс куда происходит иньекция

```
public class  RESTfulAmClientBean 
    extends BaseAmClient<RESTfulAmClientBean> 
    implements RESTfulAmClient , Serializable{
  @Inject
  private Logger logger;
  @Inject
  @AmClientTransportProducer
  private AmClientTransport restfulAmClientTransport;
```

Класс с методом-producer`ом

```
public class AmClientTransportProducerBean implements
       AmClientTransportProducer {
   @Inject
   Logger logger;
   @Inject
   private AmObjectApiSettingsManager settMgr;
   public AmClientTransportProducerBean() {}
   @Override
@ru.iteco.amobjectapi.amclients.transports.annotations.AmClientTransportProducer
   @Produces
   public AmClientTransport getAmClientTransport(@Any Instance<AmClientTransport> instance ,InjectionPoint ip){
   logger.debug("транспорт producer isAmbig:" + instance.isAmbiguous() + "  isUnsatt:" + instance.isUnsatisfied());
   instance.select(HttpAmClientTransportBean.class);
   logger.debug("транспорт producer isAmbig:" + instance.isAmbiguous() + "    isUnsatt:" + instance.isUnsatisfied());
   Iterator<AmClientTransport> it = instance.iterator();
   logger.debug("hasNext:" + it.hasNext());
   if(!instance.isUnsatisfied()){
      for (AmClientTransport transport : instance){
          logger.debug("transport class name is : " + transport.getClass().getName());
      }
   }else{
      logger.error("no AmClientTransport Implementations");
   }
    return null;
}
```

Класс HttpAmClientTransportBean

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "HttpAmClientTransport")
@Local(HttpAmClientTransport.class)
@RestfulAmClientTransport
@UnSecure
public class HttpAmClientTransportBean 
extends BaseHttpAmClientTransport<HttpAmClientTransportBean> 
implements  HttpAmClientTransport {

/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public HttpAmClientTransportBean() {
    super();
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see ru.iteco.amobjectapi.amclients.transports.http.HttpAmClientTransport#getAmClientType()
 */
@Override
public Class<HttpAmClientTransportBean> getAmClientType() {
    return HttpAmClientTransportBean.class;
}
@Override
public void execute(){

}
```

}